# JAVA: Getting the content of specific strings from text files

Tags: java, file

I have a `text` file like this:

```
  text
  text
  text
  .
  .
  @data
  instances1
  instances2
  .
  .
  instancesN
```

I want to get the contents of this file from `@data` until the end of the file, how can I do?

I found this method of `FileUtils` (from apache commons-lang) class but it's usable only if I already know the line number.

```
String ln = FileUtils.readLines(new File("arff_file/"+results.get(0)))
    .get(lineNumber);
```

Comment: read everything (with `readlines`), then iterate on the list obtained and look for `@date`

Comment: NB: list indices are starting from 0, so when using `get()` you need to use `get(lineNumber - 1)`

Comment: @RC Couldn't you just read until the `@data` and store everything after it? (instead of storing everything and then iterating through the list)

Comment: @BradySheehan sure, but if using `readlines`, you read the whole file.

Comment: @RC okay, I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Apache Commons, you can do it in one line:

```
String contents = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("arff_file/"+results.get(0)), "UTF-16").replaceAll("^.*?(?=@data)", "");
```

This works by

- reading the whole file into a single String
- using regex-based `replaceAll()` to remove (by replacing with a blank) everything up to, but not including, `@data`

The regex breakdown of `^.*?(?=@data)` is:

- `^` start of input
- `.*?` a reluctantly quantified wildcard
- `(?=@data)` a positive (non-consuming) look ahead that asserts that the next input is `@data`

A reluctant quantifier could be important to use so it won't skip past the first `@data`, in case it appears more than once in the input.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how does the `replaceAll("^.*?(?=@data)", "");` work in this context?

Comment: Replace everything which comes before @data with ""

Comment: @MarcoAcierno okay, I get it now. That's pretty clever.

Comment: @BradySheehan see edit to answer - does that explain it?

Comment: @Bohemian yes, that definitely cleared it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
String file = "fileName";
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.equals("@data"))
        nowRead(br);//I just do this for more efficiency, you can set a boolean flag instead
}
br.close();
}catch (IOException e) {
    //OMG Exception again!
}
}

static ArrayList<String> nowRead(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();// do it as you wish
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        s.add(line);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Path start = Paths.get("test.txt");
try
{
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(start);

    for (Iterator<String> it = lines.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
    {
        String line = it.next();

        if (!"@data".equals(line.trim()))
        {
            it.remove();
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(lines);
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I was reading about `Path` online so why not something like this as alternative to Bohemian code?

Maybe something could be done using `stream()` of Java 8 but not still nothing...